# get form values with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I have a JavaScript function. I need to get values from a form and send it to another page. By using "onclick" property of the form, I can send one value. But I also need to send a textbox value as well.

This is the JavaScript code:

```
<script>
function func(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","record.asp?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

this is the form:

```
<form id="record">
  value:
<select name="blabla">
  <%
  do until rs.eof
  id=rs("JobId")
  name=rs("JobName")
  rs.movenext
  %>
  <option value=<%=id%>><%=name%></option>
  <% loop %>
  </select>
  <label for="iddepartment">&nbsp;&nbsp;department name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="inputname" id="inputid" />
  <input type="button" name="addDepartment" id="addId" value="ADD" onclick="func(<%=id%>)" />
</form>
```

As you see, I can send the "id" value to record.asp successfully. But I need to send the value which user enters in the text input as well. I tried a few things but couldn't succeed. How should I change the JavaScript function and how should I change the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add query strings to a url like so `record.asp?name=value&name=value`

Also I imagine you would like to grab values from the form:

```
document.forms.<form_id>.<field_name>.value
```

**Please see the full example with asp code replaced with values**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunc(str) {

        var blabla = document.forms.record.blabla.value,
            inputname = document.forms.record.inputname.value;

        if (str === undefined || str.length === 0) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return false;
        }

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = 
                                                        xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "record.asp?q=" + str + "&blabla=" 
                      + blabla + "&inputname=" + inputname, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        return false;
    }

</script>
</head>
```

And here is the body:

```
<body>
<div id="txtHint"></div>
<form id="record" onsubmit="return myFunc(7);" method="POST" action="#">
    <select name="blabla">
        <option value="1">Foo</option>
        <option value="2">Bar</option>
    </select>
    <label for="iddepartment">&nbsp;&nbsp;department name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="inputname" id="inputid" />
    <input type="submit" name="addDepartment" id="addId" value="ADD" />
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: robbmj it works perfectly. thank you. tho in this case, the function actually doesn't neet a value like (7).. because it takes what's needed from "document.forms.record.blabla.value" and like that. anyway it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

To send multiple values by GET, you can youse & to concat.

Example:

I wanna send A (45) and B (303)

Result: ?A=45&B=303